how to retrieve all resources under given subnet using Azure Resource Graph Explorer query
I am using Azure Web App services, which have configured virtual network integration  with an outbound subnet:

I would like to list all resources which are associated with given subnet: "snet-dev".
I have created a query and run in the Azure Resource Graph Explorer:

query is:
Resources
| where type =~ "microsoft.network/networkinterfaces"
| extend subnetId = tostring(properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet.id)
| where subnetId contains "snet-dev"  
| project id, name, resourceGroup, location, subnetId

Unfortunately no results are fetched.
I have tried to run the query without the "where" but then I am getting far to many results to manualy find the resources with given subnet.
How to write a query which will return all linked resources to a given subnet?

@Sridevi Unfortunately this did not help

Could you confirm whether linked resources are all web apps or any other exists?

Just how to confirm it? I can see my 5 web apps connected to given subnet (opening every web app separately and checking Networking settings), how to find if there is anything else? ( I have not created the subnet, just specific team which handles network requests )

I got the query to fetch all web apps linked to specific subnet. Is it okay to post it as answer?

@Sridevi yes of course

I have few Azure Web App services configured virtual network integration with an outbound subnet named "snet-dev" like this:

Initially, I too got null results when I ran same query as you in my environment like this:
Resources
| where type =~ "microsoft.network/networkinterfaces"
| extend subnetId = tostring(properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet.id)
| where subnetId contains "snet-dev"  
| project id, name, resourceGroup, location, subnetId

Response:

To retrieve all Azure Web App resources under subnet named  "snet-dev" using Azure Resource Graph Explorer, you can run below query:
resources
| where type =~ "microsoft.web/sites" // Search for Azure Web Apps
| extend subnetID = tostring(properties.virtualNetworkSubnetId)
| where isnotempty(subnetID) 
| extend extractedSubnetName = tostring(split(subnetID, '/')[10]) // Extract subnet name from the full virtualNetworkSubnetId path
| where extractedSubnetName == "snet-dev" 
| project webAppId = id, webAppName = name, subnetID, extractedSubnetName

Response:


This query works, but lists only web apps. Is there any way all possible resources could be presented?

You can generalize the query to search across all resource types that contain a virtualNetworkSubnetId property. However, not all resources have the same property structure, so you might need to account for different ways subnet references are stored across resource types.
